# Text won't wrap before label (bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a bit of trouble with some css, I'd like the text to wrap so the label is on the middle right like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBIOS.png but currently it looks like this http://jsfiddle.net/yuvemL1z/ the label gets pushed under the text, if anyone can help that would be great, thank you.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">Text Test Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text<span class="label label-default pull-right">New</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">Text</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">Text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
h4 {
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.row {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.row .row {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
[class*="col-"] {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: #eee;
    background-color: rgba(86,61,124,.15);
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border: 1px solid rgba(86,61,124,.2);
}
hr {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an element to contain the text, like this:

```
<div class="col-md-4"><div class="innertext">Text Test Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</div><span class="label label-default pull-right">New</span></div>
```

Now, simply style that `.innertext` div, like this:

```
.innertext{display:inline-block; width:90%}
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tu7moprn/)